# Calling the second function in a "while" loop

Tags: python

I'm on my early python self learning path and somehow I can't get the code to execute def cadastro() whenever 1 is imputed.
Can you please assist.
Valuable contributions have been shared with me on this forum which I'm greatly appreciative of, however I remain stuck with this code.

```
lista_de_usuarios = {}

print ('BEM VINDO AO BCI')
print("PARA CADASTRO PRESSIONE 1 E 2 PARA LOGIN")

while True:

    opcao_1 = input()

    if opcao_1 == '':
        print ('NADA FOI SELECIONADO, ADEUS')
        break
    elif opcao_1 == 2:
        acesso()

    elif opcao_1 == 1:
        cadastro()

    def acesso():
        print ('Insira o seu usuário')
        user = input()
        print ('insira a sua palávra chave')
        password = input()
        if user in lista_de_usuarios:
            if lista_de_usuarios[user] == password:
                print ('ACESSO LIVRE')
            else:
                print ('A senha digitada está incorrecta')
        else:
            print('Este usuário não consta em nossa base de dados')
    acesso()

    def cadastro():
        print ('Insira o seu nome')
        nome = input()
        print ('insira a sua idade')
        idade = input()
        lista_de_usuarios[nome]=idade
    cadastro()
```

Comment: `opcao_1` is a string. Note that `"1" == 1` is `False`.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I managed to convert opcao_1 into an integer, however the problem persists.

Comment: Don't define functions inside of a list.

Comment: Yeah.. looks like you're trying to call acesso() before it's defined. Move the function definitions above the loop - that might solve it.

Comment: Hi Todd, I have moved the function definitions to the top, leaving the 'while loop' block in the bottom. Now, when i run the code, the first function definition block is executed followed by the second block, although this are meant to be executed after being called.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `"` before your numbers. Because you asked for user input and added `str()`, they can only output a string.

```
elif opcao_1 == "1":
    acesso()
elif opcao_1 == "2":
    cadastro()
```

Comment: Your comments were implemented, code updated, however the code still crashes. Please assist

Answer (score 0):

It is because the input type is a string and not a number, so your elif statement will never return true even if 1 or 2 is typed. Instead they should be:

```
elif opcao_1 == '1':
    acesso()
elif opcao_1 == '2':
    cadastro()
```

Comment: i just implemented your comments, however the code crashes.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

lista_de_usuarios = {}

```
print ('BEM VINDO AO BCI')

def opcoes():
    print("PARA CADASTRO PRESSIONE 1 E 2 PARA LOGIN")
opcoes()

def acesso():
    print ('Insira o seu usuário')
    user = input()
    print ('insira a sua palávra chave')
    password = input()
    if user in lista_de_usuarios:
        if lista_de_usuarios[user] == password:
            print ('ACESSO LIVRE')
        else:
            print ('A senha digitada está incorrecta')
    else:
        print('Este usuário não consta em nossa base de dados')
        opcoes()

def cadastro():
    print ('Insira o seu nome')
    nome = input()
    print ('insira a sua idade')
    idade = input()
    lista_de_usuarios[nome]=idade
    print ('ESTA É A LISTA COMPLETA DE USUÁRIO: ',lista_de_usuarios)


while True:



    opcao_1 = int(input())

    if opcao_1 == '':
        print ('NADA FOI SELECIONADO, ADEUS')
        break
    elif opcao_1 == 2:
        acesso()

    elif opcao_1 == 1:
        cadastro()
```

> Blockquote